# DBUS low level API - cancel waiting for connection messages

Tags: c++, dbus

I need to cancel this blocking call from another thread:
dbus_connection_read_write(conn, 0);

From the documentation I can guess that I need to unref the connection and it will be enough. Question - is this unref'ing thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by enabling resource locking in libdbus. Can be done by calling dbus_threads_init_default() atleast once.